# GeoRegionValuePlot Leaving Out Metropolitan Census Tracts

Tags: graphics, visualization, geography, geographics

## Preamble

Run this code in the preamble for a working example of what I'm dealing with.

**Census Tract Entity Store**

```
ResourceData[ResourceObject["Census Tract Entity Store"]]; // Quiet
EntityRegister[ResourceData[ResourceObject["Census Tract Entity Store"]]]; // Quiet
```

**Function Declaration**

```
f[x_] := EntityValue[EntityClass["CensusTract", "ADM2" -> x], 
   EntityProperty["CensusTract", "B19013_001E"], "Association"] // 
  Quiet
```

**List of Counties**

Click [here](https://pastebin.com/Hkk0JL26) for Pastebin of list of counties. You have to run this code in order for this example to work.

## Question

Take a look at the following line of code. It generates a map of the census tracts in the DMV area, colored by income. When I run it, having run all the code above first, I am seeing that D.C. and Baltimore are blank. See the areas I'm talking about circled in blue in the figure below. (I added the blue circles after the fact)

`GeoRegionValuePlot[<|Map[f, dmvCounties]|>, ImageSize -> 500]`

[image: Output]

**My question is: why are D.C. and Blatimore blank? How can I include them in this map as well?**

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the output of `Map[f, dmvCounties]`, you can see that there are several counties where the value is `Null` or `Missing`.

```
a = <|Map[f, dmvCounties]|>

Sort[a][[-50 ;;]]
```

[image]

I don't see DC in the output but it does look like there's a "Baltimore County" value that is null. Another way to have a look is by just plotting all the keys:

```
GeoListPlot[Keys@a, PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

Clearly something missing.

A final check is to simply run `f` on the entities you are missing:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot@
 f[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"BaltimoreCounty", "Maryland", 
    "UnitedStates"}]]
```

[image]

while `f@Entity["City", {"Washington", "DistrictOfColumbia", "UnitedStates"}]` just returns `<||>`.

Sorry I don't have a solution as to how you can include them, but the why seems that there may be no data in the dataset for those Entities.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if it has anything to do with the `ADM2` specification in my function declaration... Could it be that these metropolitan areas are `ADM1` or `ADM3`? I tried to replace these entity classes, but nothing returned!

Comment: That definitely seems plausible to me. I would guess the issue is related to them being large metropolitan areas, but I really couldn't say beyond that!